# PHP MySQL ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1 not working on all searchs

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched for an answer to this problem all over the web and here at Stackoverflow.  Nothing seems to help.
This should be a very simple function.
I have multiple records with the same content EXCEPT a field called level.  I want to find the record with the highest int value in level.  An example would be that I have multiple records with the same userid and email but the first record starts at level 1, the next may be level 2 and then the next may be level 1 again.  I want to find the record with level = 2.
My code is very simple.

```
  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT userid, email, level FROM orders WHERE userid=%s AND email=%s ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
```

For some this works correctly, returning the record with level = 2, 3, 8, 9, whatever.  For others it will only return the record with level = 1.
The field level is int length 1.
I'm running php Version 5.3.28 and MySQL 5.5.36

Any ideas anyone?
Like most, I'm in a rush.
Thanks...

I didn't realize that level was a reserved word.  I have been using the same table definitions and writing other scripts using level with no problems until now.  I am checking for errors and it is not returning any.  When checking the result with
    foreach ($row_LoginRS as $key=>$val)
    echo $key. ": ".$val. "
"; 
I normally get: 
userid: 9999 
email: email@email.com 
level: 1 (or 2 or 3).
That looks correct.
I tried enclosing  in ticks as suggested - 
    SELECT userid, email, `level` ... and/or/both ORDER BY 'level' 
and it returns: 
userid: 9999 
email: email@email.com 
level: level
My original query looks correct:

```
string(120) "
SELECT userid, email, level FROM orders WHERE userid='9999' AND email='email@email.com' ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1
"
```

and when using ticks I get:

```
string(120) "
SELECT userid, email, 'level' FROM orders WHERE userid='9999' AND email='email@email.com' ORDER BY 'level' DESC LIMIT 1
"
```

I'm not sure about the MySQL client question.  phpinfo return:
Active Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0
Client API version  5.5.36
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE  external
MYSQL_SOCKET  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE  -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient

Comment: Are your values correct? Have you `var_dumped` them?

Comment: Yes. All the values are correct

Comment: @cliff *"I'm not sure about the MySQL client question."* - We need to know what your db connection is `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, or PDO and if you are not mixing any of those together. I have made an edit to my answer below. Look under **Edit:**

Comment: While not 'reserved', note that level is a designated keyword in MySQL

Answer (score 6):

You're not checking for errors.

- `level` is a MySQL keyword
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

It requires special attention, therefore either **rename it to something other than a reserved word**, or wrap ticks around it:

```
SELECT userid, email, `level` ...
```

Check for errors in your query using the same API as you are connecting with, which is unknownst to us.

You did tag as mysql, but MySQL has 3 different APIs under a PHP environment, not counting MSSQL.

- mysql_
- mysqli_
- PDO

**Edit:**

> I tried enclosing in ticks as suggested

```
SELECT userid, email, `level` ... and/or/both ORDER BY 'level'
                      ^ tick                           ^ quote
```

> and it returns: userid: 9999 email: email@email.com level: level

and...

> My original query looks correct:
>   string(120) "SELECT userid, email, level FROM orders WHERE userid='9999' AND email='email@email.com' ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1" and when using ticks I get: string(120) "SELECT userid, email, 'level' FROM orders WHERE userid='9999' AND email='email@email.com' ORDER BY 'level' DESC LIMIT 1"

- `ORDER BY 'level'` that is being treated as a string literal, rather than a column. That too needs to be wrapped in ticks.

Change your query to:

```
"SELECT userid, email, `level` FROM orders 
 WHERE userid='9999' 
 AND email='email@email.com' 
 ORDER BY `level` DESC LIMIT 1"
```

- Ticks are not the same as single quotes.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

> I'm not sure about the MySQL client question.

We need to know if you are `mysql_`, `mysqli_` or PDO to connect with.

In either case, check for errors on the query. Choose from the following list:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php mysql_
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php mysqli_
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php PDO

> *"No errors"*

An example query to check for errors:

mysql_

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
if ( !$result ) {
    trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

also `or die(mysql_error($con))` to `mysql_query()`

or mysqli_

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($con));
}

else{ echo "Success."; }
```

`or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

or PDO

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage(); for the real error
    }
```

Comment: @SourceMatters I'm starting to know a lof of them by heart ;-)

Comment: I didn't realize that level was a reserved word.  I have been using the same table definitions and writing other scripts using level with no problems until now.  I am checking for errors and it is not returning any.  When checking the result with  , I normally get: userid: 9999 email: rinconnyc@aol.com
level: level
I tried enclosing  in ticks as suggested - SELECT userid, email, `level` ... and

Comment: Adding tick marks didn't help as stated in my original question edit.  I did change the table field from level to levels and changed the code to:  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT userid, email, levels FROM orders WHERE userid=%s AND email=%s ORDER BY levels DESC LIMIT 1", 
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));  Same problem.  No errors.  All data looks good but it is return a record with levels = 1 instead of the record with levels = 2

Comment: It's not reserved, but it is a keyword

Comment: @Strawberry When I saw your comment under the question, I edited my answer to read *"level is a MySQL keyword"* shortly after.

Comment: I'm too slow latching onto the thread of the conversation :-( But you're still suggesting that it's part of the problem! It's not! (or at least not yet)

Comment: @Strawberry No problemo ;-) *Cheers* I did upvote your comment(s). The first one initially upon seeing it.

Comment: @Strawberry as per your edited comment *"But you're still suggesting that it's part of the problem! It's not! (or at least not yet)"* - Maybe so, however it will prove to be beneficial to future readers in regards to keywords. OP has provided their own answer also, being hidden characters which I suggested it may be unicode. The keyword would have in fact played a role in this, seeing that their edited code used string literals around the column in the `where` clause, and that's a fail right there. `ORDER BY 'level'` - using quotes, not ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things jump out at me:
You're sending the value of "password" as one of your query parameters, but not really using it in the query unless their password is their email (which would be... umm... "not a best practice" :) )

try doing a var_dump($LoginRS__query) to see what your actual query string looks like. Be sure your parameters are getting populated properly.